# Create Javascript Object from splitted String

Tags: javascript, json

i am searching a "group function" for an object, which can be created from the following format:

```
"0_tags.0": {
    "common": {
    },
    "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
    }
},
"0_tags.0.Various": {
    "common": {
    },
    "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
    }
},
"0_tags.0.Various.Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung": {
    "common": {
    },
    "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
    }
},
"0_tags.0.Various.Test-String": {
    "common": {
    },
    "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
    }
},
"0_tags.0.Various.battery_charge": {
    "common": {
    },
    "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
    }
}
```

Which should dynamically result in:

```
"0_tags": {
    "0": {
        "Various": {
            "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung": {
                "common": {},
                "native": {
                    "topic": "Stromerfassung_252/Zähler0-Leistung"
                }
            },
            "Test-String": {
                "common": {},
                "native": {
                    "topic": "Stromerfassung_253/Zähler0-Leistung"
                }
            },
            "battery_charge": {
                "common": {},
                "native": {
                    "topic": "Stromerfassung_254/Zähler0-Leistung"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My start is as follows:

```
for (d in jsonArray) {
    var item = d.split('.');

    if (obj[item[0]] == undefined) {
        obj[item[0]] = {};
    }
    if (obj[item[0]][item[1]] == undefined) {
        obj[item[0]][item[1]] = {};
    }

    obj[item[0]][item[1]][item[2]] = jsonArray[d];
}
```

But this one is not dynamically doing - instead its "hard-coded" till level 2.

Do you perhaps have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Side note: don't call your object `jsonArray`. It is neither JSON, nor Array.

Comment: In your source data there is a path "0_tags.0", "common". Why in your result you don't have "0_tags", "0", "common" as a path? In other words, your input has 5 objects that have "common" and "native" keys, yet in your output two of those objects are gone. Why?

Comment: @trincot it's an example.

Comment: Yes, I understood it was an example, and it is very useful to have an example case of input with corresponding output in the question. But I am asking why two objects from the input are not retained in the output? Can you explain what the logic is for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically create the nested structure without hard-coding the levels, you can use a recursive function. This function will handle the creation of nested objects and update the appropriate properties at each level.
The `createNestedObject` function takes the parent object `obj`, the array of `keys`, and the `value` to be inserted at the deepest level. It recursively creates nested objects until the last key is reached, where it assigns the value.

Using this approach, you can handle any level of nesting in the input data dynamically, resulting in the desired output format. The `result` object will contain the transformed data as specified.

Here's a possible implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function createNestedObject(obj, keys, value) {
  let key = keys.shift();

  if (keys.length === 0) {
    obj[key] = value;
  } else {
    if (obj[key] === undefined) {
      obj[key] = {};
    }
    createNestedObject(obj[key], keys, value);
  }
}


const result = {};

for (const key in tagObject) {
  const value = tagObject[key];
  const keys = key.split('.');
  createNestedObject(result, keys, value);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```html
<script>
  const tagObject = {
    "0_tags.0": {
      "common": {},
      "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
      }
    },
    "0_tags.0.Various": {
      "common": {},
      "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
      }
    },
    "0_tags.0.Various.Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung": {
      "common": {},
      "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
      }
    },
    "0_tags.0.Various.Test-String": {
      "common": {},
      "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
      }
    },
    "0_tags.0.Various.battery_charge": {
      "common": {},
      "native": {
        "topic": "Stromerfassung_251/Zähler0-Leistung"
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Strange, @Stef, this doesn't create the output you mentioned in your question. Are you saying your question had a mistake? See my comment there, which you didn't answer yet.

Comment: @trincot as said before it was an example. Do you have a solution or are you only looking for something to talk about?

Comment: I have a solution, but it produces the output that you have in your question, and it is not the output in this answer. But before I post, I want to be sure which output you want, since you marked this answer as accepted, which left me in confusion.